# sql server order strange, the negative char

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

ex1：normal

[image]

ex2: strange

[image]

it looks like '-' has been ignored in ex2.
the  Collation is 'Chinese_PRC_CI_AS'.

Comment: try to convert tp to varchar(4) and then use order by on that converted column.. like ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),tp)

Comment: thank you,but  it got the same result,no change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the default collation of Database you have.   But, you should explicitly `COLLATE` the `ORDER BY` Clause  with `BINARY SORT`

```
select * from
(
        values ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('-1'), ('-2'), ('-3')
)a(tp)
order by tp collate Chinese_PRC_BIN
```

And, event i don't know what the order you are looking. So, the end result will look

```
tp
-1
-2
-3
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thank you.It's the right order  i want  .And ,Why it doesn't work by Chinese_PRC_CI_AS.Is there some doc?

Comment: @ggpl It depends on the `Collation` how the characters are sorted & compared. The collation `Chinese_PRC_BIN` compare & sort case and ascent sensitive like as above. It is always better to use explicitly collation to avoid problems you found.